# CSS how to vertically align text within a pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have created a pseudo element to sit over an unordered list, the css is as follows:

```css
ul.pricing-column {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}

.pricing-column.featured::after {
  content: "Most Popular";
  background: #52BDE6 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pricing-column featured">
</ul>
```

However, with this, the text inside the pseudo-element sits at the top of my element - is there a way to center it vertically?

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dqxt2r3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way? Add padding top. Little more difficult but better way, use flexbox.

These properties will do

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dqxt2r3/4/

Comment: Genuis, thank you sir - will be reading up on the 'flex' property this evening!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to center it verticaly use `top: calc(50% - 40px);` 40px is half of the element

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dqxt2r3/1/)

EDIT:

Sorry, update use `display: inline-flex;` and `align-items: center;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dqxt2r3/7/)

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my question isn't clear, I'm looking to center the text inside the pseudo element, not the element itself. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can change how you position the pseudo element then this will work.

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` and adjust the `top` and `left` values accordingly.

To center the text apply `display: table-cell;`, `text-align: center;` and `vertical-align: middle`.

```
.pricing-column.featured::after {
    content: "Most Popular";
    background: #52BDE6 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    left: -90px;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 0.9em;
    padding: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/6dqxt2r3/5/