# vertical align of text section not working

Tags: html, css

I have a problem regarding vertical alignment of 2nd text section on this site: http://enjoy-it.pl/m/m-mount-everest/

i've been trying those methods and it seems that it is not working:

1. Vertical-align:middle
2. put everything into display:table, and display:table-cell
3. combining with margin: auto + display: block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS how to vertically align text within a pseudo element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154116/css-how-to-vertically-align-text-within-a-pseudo-element) check out my answer there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical-align with bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: WHat i see, is 403, Forbidden ! nothing else.